# Inject @ActivityScoped object into a Fragment

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

How can I inject a module that is `@ActivityScoped` into a fragment.

The module I need inside the Fragment looks like this (its injected fine into the activities)

```
@ActivityScoped
class ClipManager @Inject constructor(private val activity: Activity) { ... }
```

To bind my `MainActivity` to `Activity` I am using an `ActivityModule`

```
@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @Binds
    @ActivityScoped
    internal abstract fun bindActivity(mainActivity: MainActivity): Activity
}
```

to be able to inject into my `MainActivity` i use this one

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

I am having the following dagger component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    ApplicationModule::class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityModule::class,
    FragmentModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): AppComponent.Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

with a regular context binding `ApplicationModule`

```
@Module
abstract class ApplicationModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    internal abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context
}
```

Now I am having the `FragmentModule` which enables injection into the fragments

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentModule {

    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun fragment1(): Fragment1
}
```

**How can I extend dagger to be able to inject the `ClipManager` within to `Fragment1` (which itself lives in the `MainActivity`)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your FragmentComponent a Subcomponent of your ActivityComponent. Doing this will allow the Fragment to inject anything bound in its parent component.

All you really have to do is remove `FragmentModule::class` from the list of modules on your `AppComponent` and add it to your ActivityComponent instead:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

  @ActivityScoped
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class, FragmentModule::class])
  internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

This way it will be a subcomponent of your MainActivityComponent.